# What is "dense" in DensePose?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, terminology, papers

I've recently come across an amazing work for human pose estimation: [DensePose: Dense Human Pose Estimation In The Wild](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.00434.pdf) by Facebook.

In this work, they have tackled the task of dense human pose estimation using discriminative trained models.

I do understand that "correspondence" means how well pixels in one image correspond to pixels in the second image (specifically, here - 2D to 3D).

But what does "dense" means in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In computer vision, the adjectives *dense* and *sparse* are used in a variety of tasks (e.g. [optimal flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_flow)), but they are commonly used in the context of the [correspondence problem](https://www.mia.uni-saarland.de/zimmer/phd-thesis), which is the problem of finding a map (or correspondence) between pixels of two images (e.g. two successive frames of a video). In this context, these adjectives thus refer to the number of pixels of the image that are used to solve this specific task. A *dense correspondence* is thus a correspondence between two images using all (or, at least, *many*) pixels. In other words, a dense correspondence attempts to map all (or many) pixels of an image to all (or many) pixels of another image.

In the case of [DensePose](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.00434.pdf), the correspondences are between RGB images and surface-based representation of the human body (the figures of the paper illustrates this).